# Files are not being sent to trash but being permanently deleted

Tags: xubuntu, java, trash

When I booted my computer, I noticed:

- that the Trash icon was missing from File Manager;
- this message when I tried to delete a file:

> Are you sure that you want to permanently delete "testFile"?
>   If you delete a file, it is permanently lost.

- that I can't restore already deleted files to their previous locations. I can do it manually, but there is no restore feature

I tired `apt-get update`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get update --fix-missing` to try to repair anything broken.

Everything was working fine yesterday. However, I've been working on a java project to send files to trash. I made it about a month ago, so I am not sure if it is relevant, but here is the test code:

```
public class SendToTrashTest 
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try {
            File f=new File("test11");
            f.createNewFile();
            sendToTrash(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void sendToTrash(File f)
    {
        try {
            String s[]=f.getAbsolutePath().split(File.separator);
            String baseName=s[s.length-1],name=baseName;
            File trashInfoFile=new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.local/share/Trash/info",name+".trashinfo");
            //handles duplicate files
            for(int i=2;trashInfoFile.exists();i++)
            {
                name=baseName+="."+i;
                trashInfoFile=new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.local/share/Trash/info",name+".trashinfo");
            }           
            //moves file to trash
            File trashFile=new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.local/share/Trash/files",name);
            Files.move(f.toPath(), trashFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            //creates trash info file which is used to restore the trash file
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            trashInfoFile.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(trashInfoFile);
            out.println("[Trash Info]");
            out.println("Path="+f.getAbsolutePath());
            //eg deletetion date: DeletionDate=2014-03-01T23:38:18
            out.println("DeletionDate="+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).replace(" ", "T"));
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have no idea of how to fix my problem, so any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Thunar or Nautilus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open nautilus file manager and goto edit => preferences => Behavior

[image]

Under trash select that option

I hope that helps

Comment: Appologies, I asked this question a year ago, solved it and forgot the solution. I am marking this answer as the accepted answer.